# TestNG and Guice Injection

Tags: java, testng

I would like to know if there is a way to get the object of class which has @BeforeSuite and pass it to my Test Class's constructor using Guice injection (or any other way)
Please respond as I'm struck at this point.

Comment: Maybe the Arquillian framework would be helpful. It's designed to handle this kind of thing. http://arquillian.org/ . Here's a link to the guice extension: http://arquillian.org/modules/guice-extension/

Comment: Thanks Simon... can this framework be used along with TestNG? It would also be of huge help if you can provide some samples..

Comment: Yes, it works with testNG. You can find example code on the Arquillian web site or just by searching.